What is the term/phrase in academic English Literature given to idioms/figure-of-speech/proverbs/narratives that are oxymorons/self-contradictory?

Unless the employer stuffs my mouth with gold until I gag, I will Not work for them.

What is the term/phrase in academic English Literature given to idioms/figure-of-speech/proverbs/narratives that are oxymorons/self-contradictory?

Possibly Irish bull. But I don't think you mean "self-contradictory" as much as you mean ludicrous. Or am I missing something here?

What's your problem with "stuffs my mouth with gold until I gag"? Can you give a better example? An oxymoron is certainly a self-contradictory or seemingly self-contradictory figure of speech, but not everything self-contradictory is an oxymoron.

The term you’re looking for is “oxymoron”. An oxymoron is a figure of speech that combines seemingly contradictory terms to create a unique expression. Examples include phrases like “jumbo shrimp,” “deafening silence,” and "loving hate". These self-contradictory combinations are often used in literature and everyday conversation to evoke thought and emphasize contrasts.
